# How to convert .png file to .bmp?

Tags: php, printing, png, bmp

I need to convert a .png file to .bmp; I'm using the outcome in [`printer_draw_bmp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-draw-bmp.php) to print out a barcode.

GD can generate WBMP, but as far as I can tell that's not the same as .bmp. How can I do this conversion? Or is there another way to print a .png directly?

Comment: Have you actually tried to use wbmp?

Comment: thankyou , jack :)

I tried wbmp but it doesn't work ..

Comment: Maybe you will want to highlight that in your question; it seems only speculative at this point.

Answer (score 3):

There is a opensource project on Github that allows reading and saving of BMP files (and other file formats) in PHP.

The project is called [PHP Image Magician.](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com)

Comment: the link does not work any more

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) doesn't support bmp format. But you can use [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to save file in bmp format:

```
$im = new Imagick('image.png');
$im->writeImage('image.bmp');
```

Or if you want to output image to http response:

```
$im = new Imagick('image.png');
$im->setImageFormat('bmp');
echo $im;
```

Comment: Not sure, ImageMagick is great. +1

Comment: I already install the ImageMagick and add the extension, but it always shows "Class 'Imagick' not found" . why ?

Comment: @santi_nc, have you restarted apache (or whatever server you're using)?

Comment: It works now. but I have another problem . even the image is already converted , the printer_draw_bmp() still can't load the image . it says that the image is not bitmap . is there any different between bmp and bitmap ?

Comment: @santi_nc How you stop the "Class Imagick not found" problem?