# How can I print an image with php

Tags: php

hello i put this code there:

```
$handle = printer_open ("HP Photosmart 5520 series"); 
printer_write ($handle, "jo.png"); 
printer_close ($handle);
```

But instead of printing an image that prints me text  jo.png.

Comment: [string $content](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-write.php)

Comment: yes  I  see but how to put a picture instead of text

Answer (score 1):

Try with this [printer-draw-bmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-draw-bmp.php) You have nice example in the comments of this manual.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('kitten.png');
$randomName = uniqid() . '.bmp';
imagewbmp($im, $randomName);

$handle = printer_open("HP Photosmart 5520 series");
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
printer_start_page($handle);

printer_draw_bmp($handle, $randomName, 0, 0);

printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close ($handle);

unlink($randomName);
```

Comment: it's good but my images are in PNG

Comment: check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827498/how-to-convert-png-file-to-bmp)

Comment: in fact I have a folder or my images are stored and I recovered these images to print all. therefore this method with bmp does not help me.thx

Comment: Why it's a problem to save that PNG as BMP temporary, and then delete it after it's printed.

Comment: its a problem beacause i use GD library and this one does not acccept bmp format

Comment: this is my code but it print only the image name :<?php
$dossier = opendir("images/") or die('Error '); 
if($dossier == true ){

    echo "dir open";
}
while (false !== ($f = readdir($dossier))) {
       
if (pathinfo($f,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'jpg'){
$listephotos[] = $f; 

}
}

$handle = printer_open("HP Photosmart 5520 series");



closedir($dossier);
sort($listephotos);

foreach($listephotos as $nom){
printer_write($handle, "".$nom);
}
printer_close($handle);
?>

Comment: `printer_write` will write string only, `printer_draw_bmp` will draw BMP only, there's no other way (at least that I'm aware of).